# Are there postgresql audit table best practices

Tags: database, postgresql, standards, audit

I need to implement field audit in postgresql, I just wanted to know if there are some standard way to do it

Comment: This is not the place to ask such a question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understend why

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger_91plus

Comment: You should not ask open-ended questions like this, nor ask for any standard solutions. If you are looking for a standard, you can find it out on the web all by yourself. You should elaborate your audit requirements, show us what options you have considered and why they are not adequate or what problems you have in implementing it. Those kinds of specific questions will get you specific answers.